# Get 1 year back dateTime from current dateTime in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS format

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, localdate

I need to get the datetime of 1 year back considering the current datetime. The format needed to be in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"

- ex : 2019-08-13 12:00:14.326

I tried following. But getting an error.

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(now.toString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")).minusYears(1);
```

Below Exception returned:

> DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-08-13' could not be parsed

What's the best way to do this in Java 8+ ?

Comment: `LocalDate` is not a time based class, instead you should be using `LocalDateTime` so it can take into account time component as well

Comment: By the way: Don't forget the issue with leap year.

Comment: Error message says your input string is only `"2020-08-13"`, so why did you expect it do parse with format `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"`? Why are you even attempting to parse with such a format, when you're parsing into a `LocalDate`? Since you already have a `LocalDate` from the `LocalDate.now()` call, why are you formatting it to a string just to parse it back into a `LocalDate`? Your code makes no sense at all. Just do `LocalDate yearAgo = LocalDate.now().minusYears(1);`

Comment: And don’t forget, neither a `LocalDate` nor a `LocalDateTime` can have any format. You can have the format you want in a `String` only.

Comment: @Andreas It's my bad. I haven't much worked with LocalDate or LocalDateTime. Now I understand my mistake. I think LocalDate yearAgo = LocalDate.now().minusYears(1); seems not enough in this scenario as I need both date+time. But this returns only date. Anyway, Thanks all of your valuable ideas. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LocalDate` is the wrong class for your requirement as it does not hold the time information. You can use `LocalDateTime` but I suggest you use `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` so that you can get the flexibility of using the Zone Offset and Zone ID. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html for an overview of date-time classes.

Also, keep in mind that a date or time or date-time object is an object that just holds the information about date/time; it doesn't hold any information about formatting and therefore no matter what you do when you print their objects, you will always get the output what their `toString()` methods return. In order to format these classes or in other words, to get a string representing a custom format of these objects, you have formatting API (e.g. the modern `DateTimeFormatter` or legacy `SimpleDateFormat`) at your disposal.

**A sample code:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get the current date & time at UTC
        OffsetDateTime odtNow = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println("Now at UTC: " + odtNow);

        // Get the date & time one year ago from now at UTC
        OffsetDateTime odtOneYearAgo = odtNow.minusYears(1);
        System.out.println("One year ago at UTC: " + odtNow);

        // Define a formatter for the output in the desired pattern
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

        // Format the date & time using your defined formatter
        String formattedDateTimeOneYearAgo = formatter.format(odtOneYearAgo);
        System.out.println("Date Time in the pattern, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS: " + formattedDateTimeOneYearAgo);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Now at UTC: 2020-08-13T08:50:36.277895Z
One year ago at UTC: 2020-08-13T08:50:36.277895Z
Date Time in the pattern, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS: 2019-08-13 08:50:36.277
```

Answer (score 3):

A `LocalDate` does not hold any information about hours, minutes, seconds or any unit below, instead, it holds information about year, month and day. By calling `LocalDate.now()` you are getting the date of *today* (the day of code execution).

If you need the time as well, use a `LocalDateTime`, which has a method `now()`, too, and actually consists of a `LocalDate` and a `LocalTime`.

Your error message tells you that the content of a `LocalDate` cannot be formatted using the given pattern (-`String`) `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"` because that pattern requires values for hours (`HH`), minutes (`mm`), seconds (`ss`) and milliseconds (`SSS` are *fraction of seconds* and three of them make it be milliseconds).

For parsing `String`s or formatting datetimes, a `LocalDateTime` may be suitable but if you want to reliably add or subtract a `year` or any other amount of time, you'd rather use a class that considers time zones, offsets and daylight saving like `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`...

Answer (score 2):

May not be the `best` way, but this will do it

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now().minusYears(1);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

System.out.println(date.format(formatter));
```

Comment: `LocalDateTime.now().minusYears(1)` may return invalid time. E.g. if now was `2020-03-10 02:30`, then would be `2019-03-10 02:30`, but that time doesn't exist in e.g. US Eastern Timezone. If you used `ZonedDateTime`, then it would return a valid `2019-03-10 03:30` time.

Comment: Just out of interest, why does `2019-03-10 02:30` not exist in US Eastern Timezone?

Comment: @Andreas Given `LocalDateTime` is a datetime without time zone information, you can't expect it to abide by timezone rules.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know, that's why I suggested using `ZonedDateTime` instead, so the resultant value is valid.

Comment: @ehmkey Because at 2:00 AM on Mar 10, 2019, the clock is moved 1 hour forward to 3:00 AM for **Daylight Savings Time**. As such, 2:30 AM does no exist for that date, the entire hour is skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want date+time from 1 year back, but you give it only a date (LocalDate). If you just want the date, all you need to do is:

```
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate then = now.minusYears(1);
```

And if you want the timestamp also, then:

```
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime then = now.minusYears(1);
```

And so on for other objects.

Comment: `LocalDateTime.now().minusYears(1)` may return invalid time. E.g. if now was `2020-03-10 02:30`, then would be `2019-03-10 02:30`, but that time doesn't exist in e.g. US Eastern Timezone.

Comment: LocalDateTime has no concept of timezone. So "that time doesn't exist in US/Eastern" doesn't mean anything in the context of LocalDateTime. When you convert LocalDateTime to a ZonedDateTime with an appropriate timezone argument (`ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime, ZoneId)`, the resulting value will be adjusted for DST as per rules.

Comment: But that assumes OP knows to convert to `ZonedDateTime`, which is unlikely, since there is no mention of that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you should use LocalDateTime instead of LocalDate.

Your exception was thrown because your input String is in ISO_DATE_TIME format

[Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--)

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String now = dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now());
LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(now, dateTimeFormatter);
```